# How to hide or show controls while selecting mutilple checkboxes in orbeon form

Tags: orbeon

I have a requirement in which I have multiple checkboxes.
On selecting one checkbox, I want to unhide some input field which is possible but if I select multiple checkbox including one which unhides the field, the input field is not visible.

For only one checkbox value, I am using  tokenize(../@control-value, '\s+') = 'some Value'
and also how do I use multiple condition ? Is is possible to use '&&' and '||'  in Orbeon. Also please tell me how to use multiple checkboxes value to unhide the input field.

Answer (score 0):

In XPath, which is the language Orbeon Forms uses for formulas "and" is expressed with `and` and "or" with `or` (so no `&&` and `||` as is the case in many languages).

So now it comes down to what your condition is, something like "show the control if this checkbox is selected but no other checkbox is selected". Maybe the following could do the trick:

```xml
tokenize(../@control-value, '\s+') = 'some Value' and
not(count(tokenize(../@control-value, '\s+')) gt 1)
```

or:

```xml
let $tokens := tokenize(../@control-value, '\s+')
return
    $tokens = 'some Value' and not(count($tokens) gt 1)
```

If you are using Form Runner, and use the `xxf:split()` function:

```xml
let $tokens := xxf:split($my-control)
return
    $tokens = 'some Value' and not(count($tokens) gt 1)
```

Comment: if we have multiple checkboxes selected and we compare the values , we need to give all the combination of the values for comparison because the values of the checkbox control are in order of the selection and separated by spaces. How can we solve this problem in orbeon ? @ebruchez

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Is this a separate question? The logic you are describing in your original question doesn't seem to require testing on other values. But if so, I have shown above how you an extract the tokens to the `$tokens` variable, and then check whether values belong to that list of tokens. Does that help?